# How to read .dmp file in node.js

Tags: node.js, electron, node.js-fs

I am trying to read the .dmp file using nodejs Filesystem but it is not working.
Can someone please help me

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('test.dmp', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data.toString());
});
```

I have tried ascii, base64 decoding and toString() method too.

Comment: Where is this fille coming from?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Konrad I have .dmp file from electron app but I want to read it as normal text .
Camilo I am not getting any error but I am not able to read the data as it comes in different format like 
�.�ϩ'��Fr��f�m%7M.�ƈ�v�J↨

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nikita-graf/e7d62b0036e5b176f2f1cc072a12bdd5

Comment: Thank you Konrad I will check that link.

Comment: @Konrad I have tried that but no luck 
the output coming as json file with  {
  "filename": "0cf724ae06f35f05efe0a61e19aa2a41"
}